# Remove 5th position character From column using MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

I want remove 5th character from column using MYSQL Query.

My column lokks like

```
PRSW000000001
PRSW000000002
PRSW000000003
PRSW000000004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) like LEFT and RIGHT, and CONCAT the final result.

> ```
> create table tbl(`Order` varchar(20));
> insert into tbl values
> ('PRSW000000001'),
> ('PRSW000000002'),
> ('PRSW000000003'),
> ('PRSW000000004');
> ```

> ```
> update tbl
> set `Order` = concat(left(`Order`, 4), right(`Order`, length(`Order`) - 5));
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | Order        |
> | :----------- |
> | PRSW00000001 |
> | PRSW00000002 |
> | PRSW00000003 |
> | PRSW00000004 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=66a703652c9cb68cf327899829fff4d7)*

Comment: my table column name is Order just need delete 5th position. i can remove through c# code but i need to remove from MySQL database. column contains 1000 records..

Comment: Please do not use reserved words as `Order`

Comment: I'm glad to help